# CSS / ZPT / Plone

Tags: css, plone, zpt

I  tried using CSS in ZPT page for Plone. The only way it worked was as inline css. Using the style tag in the header didn't work, neither trying to use a linked css file.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use that specific css only in that template then first you will have to register your css resources directory (in the browser module) like this:

```xml
<!-- Register the resource directory for stylesheets -->
<browser:resourceDirectory
    name="[YOUR_PLONE_PRODUCT].styles"
    directory="styles"
    layer=".interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
    />
```

And then use it like this in your template:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      lang="en"
      metal:use-macro="here/main_template/macros/master"
      i18n:domain="[YOUR_PLONE_PRODUCT]">

<metal:slot fill-slot="css_slot">
    <link href="myspecialstyle.css"
       rel="stylesheet"
       type="text/css" 
       tal:attributes="href string:${context/portal_url}/++resource++[YOUR_PLONE_PRODUCT].styles/myspecialstyle.css"/>
</metal:slot>

<body>
    <metal:main fill-slot="main">
     ...
```

Here's some useful doc:

- http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates_css_and_javascripts/css.html
- http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates_css_and_javascripts/template_basics.html
- http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/buildingblocks/skin/style-sheets/css

Comment: Ciao Giacomo! Grazie mille :)